# Losing Bootstrap CSS after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

there is a dropdown which is binded to a function which calls another main function, the page then postbacks and the css of all the controls gets removed automatically.PLS HELP I AM STUCK FOR HOURS NOW!

NOTE : after postback the data is binded automatically as you may see in picture 2
Before postback

Using following scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-mobile-slide-menu.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-mobile-slide-menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mobile-friendly-tooltip.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/mobile-friendly-tooltip.js"></script>
```

Below is the picture before postback
[image: BEFORE POSTBACK]

Below is the picture after postback.

[image: After Postback]

Comment: I would assume you're calling some JS function to initialise those select controls when the page loads. You need to do the same after the postback.

Comment: You should check 2 things. When it doesn't work, do a view source. Is the css there? Is the class name properly on the dropdown? The css you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, as per my understanding, we are not initializing any js function, we have just added "jquery-mobile-slide-menu.css" links and other related scripts in <script> tag and these scripts tags are added inside <head> tags of Master Page. Hence on page load, the mobile js automatically understands any dropdown or textbox and adds respective div with css to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just found out that reloading js file does the job!, due to partial postback, the div and span got removed, got all those with reloading js files.

following link helped alot.
[Reload javascript file after an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594408/reload-javascript-file-after-an-ajax-request)