# What DOM event will register the completion of a search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I just read an article about using snippets in Chrome Dev Tools, and it's immediately applicable to an issue I'm working on. I need to baseline the performance of a particular kind of search on our Web site, so I started writing a snippet to measure the elapsed time from button click to Ajax refresh. The Ajax refresh is the part I'm having trouble with though. What event will fire once the search results are returned, such that I can grab the event and mark the elapsed time?

Here's what I have so far:

```
var startSearch, endSearch, elapsedTime;
var btn = document.querySelector('button.btn');
var searchContentWrapper = document.querySelector('div.searchContents');

sessionStorage.removeItem('startSearch');
sessionStorage.removeItem('endSearch');

$(btn).on('click', function() {
    startSearch = new Date();
    sessionStorage.setItem('startSearch', startSearch.getTime());
    console.info('%cSearch started: ' + startSearch, 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
});

$(searchContentWrapper).on('ajaxready', function() {
    endSearch = new Date();
    sessionStorage.setItem('endSearch', endSearch.getTime());
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('startSearch')) {
        console.info('%cSearch ended: ' + endSearch, 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
        elapsedTime = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('endSearch')) - parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('startSearch'));
        console.info('%cSearch Duration: ' + elapsedTime + 'ms', 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
    };    
});
```

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer based on the response from @Michaël to the question at [Reload javascript file after an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594408/reload-javascript-file-after-an-ajax-request). Here's the result:

```
var startSearch, endSearch, elapsedTime;
var btn = document.querySelector('button.btn');
var searchContentWrapper = document.querySelector('div.searchContents');

sessionStorage.removeItem('startSearch');
sessionStorage.removeItem('endSearch');

$(btn).on('click', function() {
    console.clear();
    startSearch = new Date();
    sessionStorage.setItem('startSearch', startSearch.getTime());
    console.info('%cSearch started: ' + startSearch, 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
});

$('body').on('ajaxready', searchContentWrapper, function(e) {
    endSearch = new Date();
    sessionStorage.setItem('endSearch', endSearch.getTime());
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('startSearch')) {
        console.info('%cSearch ended: ' + endSearch, 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
        elapsedTime = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('endSearch')) - parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('startSearch'));
        console.info('%cSearch Duration: ' + elapsedTime + 'ms', 'color:firebrick;font-size:18px');
    };    
});
```